# Xml to Text Conversion Error

Tags: xml, linux, text

I want to convert xml file into text file for this purpose I have used xmlto command in linux `xmlto txt myfile.xml`
No way to convert HTML to text found. Try either installing text web browser(lynx/w3m/links) or use option --with-fop

I have used this command then

```
xmlto --with-fop txt myfile.xml
```

After using this command I got a warning

Warning: fop not found or not executable.

and then same error.

Please tell me how to fix this error or how can I convert my xml file to text file.

Comment: What appears to be the [official documentation](http://cyberelk.net/tim/xmlto/re01.html) does not mention your switch  *with-fop*. Without giving the style sheet an answer must be very superficial.  Note, that "conversion" is somewhat misleading: you need to provide in the style sheet very detailed information, which elements are to be converted in what way.

Comment: Maybe use FOP instead? https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the warning `Warning: fop not found or not executable.` by installing the fop package. `yum install fop` or `apt install fop`